# Why interface cant be used in kotlin inner class?

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
class SelectionRAdapter(var list: ArrayList<Image>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectionRAdapter.FolderRViewHolder>() {

    inner class FolderRViewHolder(var view: View) : 
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            view.checkbox_container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("59FFFFFF"))
        }

        interface OnItemSelectListener {

        }
    }

}
```

when I try add interface to kotlin inner class it shows interface not allowed here exception may i know the reason behind it? when i trying communicate with inner class with parent class using interface

Comment: The reason seems to be the keyword `inner` in the declaration of `FolderRViewHolder`, if you remove it, this error will disappear (it does so in Kotlin Playground, at least)... I think the interface is not allowed there because it wouldn't be visible (enough).

Comment: Inside inner classes you can only declare other inner classes... Inner classes have a strong interdependency to its outer part. Without an object of the outer class they can not be initialized and they carry the reference to that outer object in their own instances. Interfaces however (and also other non-inner-classes (abstract, enum, whatever)) should not require the outer, nor the inner object in order to be able to implement or instantiate such a type...

Comment: in order to have implementations for such an interface it would mean, that the implementations could only be inside that inner class, which basically defeats the purpose of having such an interface... (if that interface within an inline class would be possible, which it isn't)... so: why do you think you want an interface within an inner class?